# Significance level of kwallis2 test in Stata

Tags: stata, kruskal-wallis-test

I have a question concerning the use of the `kwallis2` test in Stata. If looking at the multiple comparison output, I receive a probability and (NS) or (S).
What does the probability there mean and to what does the program compare this value to reach the outcome significant or not? I suppose that the standard 5% significance level is used. But I also see some adjusted p-value for significance... I am a little confused about the output given by this test.

Another question: How can the significance level be changed?

I hope (and am thankful) for good explanations!

Comment: The single p-values are compared to the critical value used by the program and reported as _Adjusted p-value for significance_. If for some reasons you don't like that critical value and, for example, you want to use an $\alpha=0.01$, then you can compare the single p-values for the different comparisons with your $\alpha$ and forget about the (S) and (NS) output.

Comment: Thank you! But which is the standard significance level used for kwallis2? The adjusted p-value for my test is 0.0041. This is not even close to the 1% significance level. Do you know how the program gets to the adjusted p-value? Thanks again.

Comment: Looking at the code behind `kwallis2`, in the case of multiple comparisons between groups (i.e. all the possible pairwise comparisons), the critical value $\alpha'$ is calculated as $\alpha/(k*(k-1))$, where $\alpha=0.05$ by default (but can be modified) and $k$ is the number of groups. If you choose a control group and compare all the other groups versus that one, then $\alpha' =  \alpha/(2*(k-1))$

Comment: @KatharinaHilken Welcome to the site! Some tips: your posts are automatically signed with your username, so there is no need to do it manually; and if some answer suits your needs, you can "accept it" by pressing green tick mark next to it -- you and the answer author will get a rep bonus and other users can see that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 4):

The single p-values from the multiple comparisons are compared to the critical value computed by the `kwallis2` command and reported as *"Adjusted p-value for significance"*. If for some reasons you don't like that critical value and, for example, you want to use an $\alpha=0.01$, then you can compare the single p-values for the different pairwise comparisons with your $\alpha$ and forget about the `(S)` and `(NS)` output.

Looking at the code behind `kwallis2`, in the case of multiple comparisons between groups (i.e. all the possible pairwise comparisons), the critical value $\alpha'$ is calculated as $\alpha/(k∗(k−1))$, where $\alpha=0.05$ by default (but can be modified using `set level` before running `kwallis2`) and $k$ is the number of groups. If you choose a control group and compare all the other groups versus that one, then $\alpha'=\alpha/(2∗(k−1))$

For example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. set level 90 // (i.e. alpha = 0.1)

. kwallis2 length, by(rep78) control(1)

One-way analysis of variance by ranks (Kruskal-Wallis Test)
[omitted output]
(Adjusted p-value for significance is 0.012500)
[omitted output]

. di 0.1/(2*4)
.0125
```

Comment: if k is the number of groups, the total possible pairwise comparisons would be k*(k-1)/2, so the α ′ should be 2α/(k∗(k−1)).

Comment: Good catch, @Qin.  Welcome to our site!